# Python Socket: Storing 'connections'?

Tags: python, python-sockets

I have multi-threaded python socket server:

```
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
```

And i need to store 'connection' to use for other thread.

How to do that?

Comment: Please what do you mean by "store"? Can you give us more of your code perhaps?

Comment: @Peter Majko I can explain od course. For example: there are connected 2 clients, both have for example unique id, and if client 1 send specified data, server sends to client 2 some data. My server creates thread for every connection

Comment: More code would help really. Your explanation in words is not enough. I have the same :) socket server in multithreading, in multiprocessing, based on twisted, based on socketserver and even socket. However I do not understand WHERE in your code you have client 1, client 2, where do you handle connection events, etc...

Comment: @Peter Majko, I'll see tomorrow your 'list' example, if that wouldn't satisfy me, i'll show my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a list?

```
connections = []
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
connections.append(connection)

connection[0]  # this is your connection
```

Answer (score 1):

right, when you use s.accept(), it creates like a subchannel you can talk to that client privatly in. so, if you do this:`connections.append(connection)`, you can then select the one in the list you want and go`connections[i].send(str.encode("xyz"))`
or, if you just want to send a message to every client, just use `sock.send("xyz")`, which will send it to everyone. hope this is helpfull :)